# 'npm run build' (ejected project has SCSS loader) error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader, npm-run

My React project (made with create-react-app) was ejected before I started the project. I included an SCSS loader in the webpack file.

Now, when I try to run 'npm run build', the following error gets shown:

```
Invalid CSS after "i": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "import React from '"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where exactly I had gone wrong, but it might have been something with css-loader.

I created a fresh project (didn't eject the project this time), installed `node-sass-chokidar` [[guide for using sass/scss in your React project]](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc), copied my `src` folder into the new project, installed all the other dependencies, and finally changed the import statements from '.scss' to '.css'.

This worked.